# Class Name prop value error: left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects

Tags: reactjs

Using react, tailwind and typescript I want to conditionally add a class name property. If addRing is true, then I want to pass ring-black as a prop value, else I want to pass ring-white.

I tried the code below but I am getting the error: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects ts(2695).
Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
<button className={
    (`rounded-xl shadow-md`,
    addRing ? `ring-black` : `ring-white`)
}>Button name</button>
```

Comment: You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator - `\`rounded-xl shadow-md\`` isn't actually going to be used at all. I'd guess you intended the conditional expression to go _in_ the template string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`className` expects you to provide **a string**.

```
(`rounded-xl shadow-md`,
    addRing ? `ring-black` : `ring-white`)
```

is not a string.

It should be something like this:

```
className = {`rounded-xl shadow-md ${addRing ? "ring-black" : "ring-white"}`}
```

See [template literals documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more info.